# Is it possible to compare two different region of mapview and find there difference?

Tags: iphone, xcode, mapkit, region

I am working on an iPhone map view app. I want to compare two regions and find their differences. For example I have two regions, the last displayed region and current displayed region, and I want know if they are equal or different and how much of the region is changed. So, I added annotations only on the changed region. If anybody knows than please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method may be help you. this may call when ever region change.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"#### %f:%f - %f:%f",mapView1.region.span,mapView1.region.span,mapView1.region.center.latitude,mapView1.region.center.longitude);
}
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for help.But I am confuse about to find difference between two region and set this difference as third region.Thanks anyway.